# Function is continuous or not

Tags: calculus

If $f$ is a function defined on $[0, 1]$ for which 
$f'(\frac{1}{2})$
 exists but$f'(\frac{1}{2})$ is not an element in $[0,1]$

then f is 
discontinuous at
$x=\frac{1}{2}$.
I need to find the statment is true or false and my conclusions are

- the statement is true  since ,if an inverse function exits and the domain of the inverse fuction should be the range of the function,in this case it fails.
  Is my analogy correct please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in the problem says anything about $f$ having an inverse. Consider the function $f(x)=3x$. What is $f'\left(\frac12\right)$? Is $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$?

**Added:** In fact, a function $f$ that is defined on an interval $[a,b]$ and has a derivative at a point $c\in(a,b)$ is **always** continuous at $c$. This is a standard result that is mentioned in just about all elementary calculus texts and proved in some.

Comment: here $f'(x)=3$ and how can find $f'(\frac{1}{2})$ is it 3 ? since $f'(x)$ is constant and since the function is $y=mx$ its is continious at every point am i right? so i think $f$ is continious at $[0,1]$

Comment: @Bijujose: Yes, that’s right: $f'\left(\frac12\right)=3$, which is not in $[0,1]$, but the function $f$ is continuous on all of $[0,1]$. In particular, it’s continuous at $1/2$.

Comment: thanks Brian for helping ,i think i am a bit lack in elementary calculus ,so i need to make a concrete foundation in the basics,and also thanks for pointing out the theorem mentioned above